# Spring Data JPA Specification Predicate for a @OneToMany Collection not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

For background:

I have built a module that captures a list of a historical events that occur against an asset over its life and using JPA specifications using spring-data-jpa with hibernate to run the dynamic query using the JPA SpecificationExecutor interface. I have the following historical event JPA object with a many to one asset this historical event is directly against and other associated assets this historical event is also associated with defined in a many-to-many relationship. I am trying to write a JPA Specification predicate that pulls all historical events for a given asset that the asset is either directly against or associated too by using the includeAssociations flag in the predicate. When I try to execute the predicate I am not getting the correct results when I have the includeAssociations flag set to true. I would expect it would by default return at a minimum all the historical events they are directly as if the includeAssociations was false plus any ones they are indirectly associated with. I need help figuring out why this predicate is not returning back what I would expect. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my Historical Event JPA object:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "LC_HIST_EVENT_TAB")
   public class HistoricalEvent extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<HistoricalEvent>, Serializable 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Asset.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "ASSET_ID")
private Asset asset;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Asset.class)
@JoinTable(name = "LC_HIST_EVENT_ASSETS", joinColumns =
  {
    @JoinColumn(name = "HIST_EVENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
  }, inverseJoinColumns =
  {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSET_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
  }, uniqueConstraints =
  {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =
    {
        "HIST_EVENT_ID", "ASSET_ID"
    })
})
@BatchSize(size=10)
@OrderBy("partCatalogItem.partID, serialNumber ASC")
private Set<Asset> associatedAssets;

@Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = true)
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar startDate;

@Column(name = "END_DATE", nullable = true)
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar endDate;
}
```

JPA Metamodel for Historical Event:

```
@StaticMetamodel(HistoricalEvent.class)
public class HistoricalEvent_ extends BaseEntity_
{
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, Asset> asset;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<HistoricalEvent, Asset> associatedAssets;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, Calendar> startDate;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, Calendar> endDate;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, String> type;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, String> description;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<HistoricalEvent, HistoricalEvent> triggeringEvent;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<HistoricalEvent, HistoricalEvent> associatedEvents;
    public static volatile MapAttribute<HistoricalEvent, String, HistoricalEventMap> data;
}
```

Here is my Asset JPA Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LC_ASSET_TAB")
public class Asset extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<Asset>, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = PartCatalog.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PART_CATALOG_ID", nullable = false)
    private PartCatalog partCatalogItem;

    @Column(name = "SERIAL_NO", nullable = false)
    private String serialNumber;

    @Column(name = "DATE_INTO_SERVICE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dateIntoService;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "asset", targetEntity = AssetMap.class)
    @MapKey(name = "fieldName")
    @BatchSize(size=25)
    private Map<String, AssetMap> data;
}
```

Asset Metamodel:

```
@StaticMetamodel(PartCatalog.class)
public class PartCatalog_ extends BaseEntity_
{
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> partID;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> nsn;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> description;
    public static volatile MapAttribute<PartCatalog, String, PartCatalogMap> data;
}
```

Here is my Part Catalog JPA object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LC_PART_CATALOG_TAB")
    public class PartCatalog extends BaseEntity implements Comparable<PartCatalog>, Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "PART_ID", length=100, nullable = false)
private String partID;

@Column(name = "NSN", length=100, nullable = true)
private String nsn;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length=250, nullable = false)
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "partCatalogItem", targetEntity = PartCatalogMap.class)
@MapKey(name = "fieldName")
private Map<String, PartCatalogMap> data;
```

}

Part Catalog Metamodel:

```
@StaticMetamodel(PartCatalog.class)
public class PartCatalog_ extends BaseEntity_
{
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> partID;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> nsn;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PartCatalog, String> description;
    public static volatile MapAttribute<PartCatalog, String, PartCatalogMap> data;
}
```

Specification Predicate for returning historical events by a given Part Number and Serial Number:

PROBLEM: If includeAssociations is false, it returns fine however soon as it is true, it returns the wrong list of associations and never returns any results from the events the asset is directly tied too like if the includeAssociations was false. This is where I need help how to best write the criteria builder query to properly pull the data.

These are the two JPQL queries I am trying to combine into the Predicate using the Criteria API:

Normal:

```
@Query("SELECT he FROM HistoricalEvent he WHERE he.asset.partCatalogItem.partID =:partID AND he.asset.serialNumber =:serialNumber " +
            "AND he.startDate >:startDate AND he.endDate <:endDate")
```

Association:

```
@Query("SELECT he FROM HistoricalEvent he INNER JOIN he.associatedAssets associated WHERE associated.partCatalogItem.partID =:partID AND associated.serialNumber =:serialNumber " +
            "AND he.startDate >:startDate AND he.endDate <:endDate");



/**
 * Creates a specification used to find historical events by a given asset part number and serial
 * parameter.
 *
 * @param partID - part identifier
 * @Param serialNumber
 * @return Historical Event Specification
 */
public static Specification<HistoricalEvent> hasPartAndSerial(final String partID, final String serialNumber, final Boolean includeAssociations) 
{

    return new Specification<HistoricalEvent>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<HistoricalEvent> historicalEventRoot,
                CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            if (partID == null || partID == "")
            {
                return null;
            }

            if(serialNumber == null || serialNumber =="")
            {
                return null;
            }

            Path<Asset> assetOnEvent = historicalEventRoot.get(HistoricalEvent_.asset);
            Path<PartCatalog> partCatalogItem = assetOnEvent.get(Asset_.partCatalogItem);
            Expression<String> partIdToMatch = partCatalogItem.get(PartCatalog_.partID);
            Expression<String> serialToMatch = assetOnEvent.get(Asset_.serialNumber);

            if(includeAssociations)
            {
                SetJoin<HistoricalEvent, Asset> assetsAssociatedToEvent = historicalEventRoot.join(HistoricalEvent_.associatedAssets);
                Path<PartCatalog> partCatalogItemFromAssociatedAsset = assetsAssociatedToEvent.get(Asset_.partCatalogItem);
                Expression<String> partIdToMatchFromAssociatedAsset = partCatalogItemFromAssociatedAsset.get(PartCatalog_.partID);
                Expression<String> serialToMatchFromAssociatedAsset = assetsAssociatedToEvent.get(Asset_.serialNumber);


                return cb.or(cb.and(cb.equal(cb.lower(partIdToMatch), partID.toLowerCase()), cb.equal(cb.lower(serialToMatch), serialNumber.toLowerCase())), 
                             cb.and(cb.equal(cb.lower(partIdToMatchFromAssociatedAsset), partID.toLowerCase()), cb.equal(cb.lower(serialToMatchFromAssociatedAsset), serialNumber.toLowerCase())));
            }
            else
            {
                return cb.and(cb.equal(cb.lower(partIdToMatch), partID.toLowerCase()), cb.equal(cb.lower(serialToMatch), serialNumber.toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Finally I am calling this to find the historical events:

```
@Override
    public Page<HistoricalEvent> getByCriteria(String type, String partID,
            String serialNumber, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate,
            Boolean includeAssociations, Integer pageIndex, Integer recordsPerPage) 
    {

        LOGGER.info("HistoricalEventDatabaseServiceImpl - getByCriteria() - Searching historical event repository for type of " + type + " , part id of " + partID + 
                " , serial number of " + serialNumber + " , start date of " + startDate + " , end date of " + endDate + ", include associations flag of " + includeAssociations
                + " , pageIndex " + pageIndex + " and records per page of " + recordsPerPage);

        Page<HistoricalEvent> requestedPage = historicalEventRepository.findAll(Specifications
                .where(HistoricalEventSpecifications.hasType(type))
                .and(HistoricalEventSpecifications.greaterThanOrEqualToStartDate(startDate))
                .and(HistoricalEventSpecifications.lessThanOrEqualToEndDate(endDate))
                .and(HistoricalEventSpecifications.hasPartAndSerial(partID, serialNumber, includeAssociations)),  
                    DatabaseServicePagingUtil.getHistoricalEventPagingSpecification(pageIndex, recordsPerPage));

        LOGGER.info("HistoricalEventDatabaseServiceImpl - getByCriteria() - Found " + requestedPage.getTotalElements() + " that will comprise " + requestedPage.getTotalPages() + " pages of content.");

        return requestedPage;
    }                                             UPDATE: i have been able to get the specification if the historical event was either directly or indirectly associated working however using the following Predicate 1 = cb.equals(cb.lower(partIDToMatch, partID.toLowercase());          Predicate2 = cb.equals(cb.lower(serialToMatch), serialNumber.toLowercase();              Predicate3 = cb.or(Predicate1, Predicate2 );         Predicate4 = cb.equals(cb.lower(partIDToMatchFromAssociatedAsset), partIDToMatch.toLowercase());    Predicate5 = cb.equals(cb.lower(serialNumberFromAssociatedAsset), serialNumberToMatch.toLowercase());                 Predicate6 = cb.and(Predicate4, Predicate5);                                                        Predicate7 = cb.or(Predicate3,Predicate6);            When i return Predicate I only get results matching Predicate6 not either one as i would expect. I want it to pull events where either predicate condition returns a record. Each predicate returns the right data but when i use the cb.or it doesnt combine results as i would expect. What am I missing?
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start printing the query and parameters value that are bean generated, just enable this properties.

After that you have to analyze your query and make some tests with different combinations to check your jpa specification are falling.

There is no magic way to do that and it's hard and painful :(

Good look